# Configurar sp Crystal reports para imprimir directamente un informe

Tags: crystal-reports, sap

Actualmente estoy desarrollando varios informes para la empresa en la cual trabajo, los informes son diseñados en crystal reports. Mi gran inconveniente es que para poder imprimir los informes primeramente debo exportarlos a pdf y luego si imprimir. Mi pregunta es ¿Es posible configurar un icono en el cual al dar clic pueda realizar la impresion del informe sin necesidad de exportarlo a pdf o me abra el asistente de impresion?

uso la version: 13.0.18
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

al dar clic en el icono de imprimir genera un asistente de exportacion, me gustaria que fuera un asistente de impresion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Crystal reports version free, trae el control activeX inactivo por defecto. Cree una forma con la cual pudiera imprimir directamente y lograr algo similar a lo que requería. Realizado a partir de una metodo el cual obtuviera el informe que se ha seleccionado, una vez realizado el proceso le indico que seleccione la impresora predeterminada y luego que se conecte a la base de datos.

```
private void metodoprint(){

            //Response.Redirect("../Visor/ConstruirReporte.aspx?Reporte=CRE9&id=" + TextBoxRecibo.Text);
            string sDatosVisorReportesCrystal = Request.QueryString["DatosVisorReportes"];

            DatosVisorReportesCrystal datosVisorReportesCrystal = Utilidades.UrlDecodeFromString<DatosVisorReportesCrystal>(sDatosVisorReportesCrystal);

            string urlReporte = Server.MapPath(datosVisorReportesCrystal.UrlOrigen);

            reporte.Load(urlReporte);

            NameValueCollection parametros = datosVisorReportesCrystal.Parametros;

            if (parametros != null)
            {
                foreach (string s in parametros.AllKeys)
                {
                    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s))
                    {
                        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(parametros[s]))
                            reporte.SetParameterValue(s, parametros[s]);
                        else reporte.SetParameterValue(s, null);
                    }

                }
            }

            CrystalReportViewer1.SelectionFormula = datosVisorReportesCrystal.Filtro;

            CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = reporte;

            foreach (TableLogOnInfo tlf in CrystalReportViewer1.LogOnInfo)
            {
                tlf.ConnectionInfo = ConexionCrystal.getLogOnInfo().ConnectionInfo;
            }

            // CORRESPONDE A LA CONFIGURACION DE LA IMPRESARORA PREDETERMINADA

            //  RptParamsWithType = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            string NombreImpresora = "";//Donde guardare el nombre de la impresora por defecto

            //Busco la impresora por defecto
            for (int i = 0; i < PrinterSettings.InstalledPrinters.Count; i++)
            {
                PrinterSettings a = new PrinterSettings();
                a.PrinterName = PrinterSettings.InstalledPrinters[i].ToString();
                if (a.IsDefaultPrinter)
                {
                    NombreImpresora = PrinterSettings.InstalledPrinters[i].ToString();

                }
            }

            CrystalReportViewer1.DataBind();
            CrystalReportViewer1.PrintMode = CrystalDecisions.Web.PrintMode.ActiveX;
            PrinterSettings impresora = new PrinterSettings();
            impresora.PrinterName = NombreImpresora;
            reporte.SetDatabaseLogon("user", "psw.", "nameserver", "db");
            reporte.PrintToPrinter(1, false, 0, 0);
            }
```

espero les pueda ayudar a los que tengan este misma dificultad

Answer (score 0):

si usas el método PrintToPrinter imprimes directamente por la impresora predeterminada si tener que mostrar o imprimir el informe:

Suponiendo que tu informe se llamara Informe

```
private void imprimeCR()
{
Informe CR = new InformeCR();
CR.PrintToPrinter(1, false, 0, 0);
CR.Close();
CR.Dispose();
}
```

Saludos

Comment: de hecho me serviria para recibos de abono que requieren ser impresos directamente, pero para esta ocasion es necesario ver el informe y luego de verlo si imprimirlo.

Comment: Desconozco como tienes hecha la aplicación pero suponiendo que los informes los muestras en un formulario independiente,Se me ocurre que puedes hacer una cosa, desde el formulario que llamas al visor:private void imprimir informe()
{
FormVisor f= new FormVisor();
//Pon aqui los datos para mostrar tu informe
f.ShowDialog();
if (MessageBox.Show("QUIERES IMPRIMIR?", "CONFIRMACIÓN", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question) == DialogResult.Yes)
{
f.imprimirCR();
}
}